# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linear maps from $U$ to $V$, show that $\alpha+\beta$ is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My first thought was to show that $\alpha=\beta$, by writing,

$$\alpha(u) = \alpha\left(\sum u_ie_i\right) = \sum u_i\alpha(e_i) = \sum u_if(e_i) = \beta\left(\sum u_ie_i\right) = \beta(u)$$

Where $u\in U$, $R = (e_i,\ldots,e_n)$ is a basis for $U$, and $f:R \to V.$

Comment: How could you possibly show $\alpha=\beta$? Are you suggesting *all* linear maps are the same, i.e. there is only one linear map $U\to V$? This is not true for most $U,V$.

Comment: Note that $\alpha+\beta$ is defined by $(\alpha+\beta)(u) = \alpha(u)+\beta(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why $\alpha=\beta$? You proved that any two linear maps are equal, thats obviusly false. And whats $f$ and $R$. If you want to prove that given two linear maps, their sum is also linear then you have to proceed like this $$(\alpha+\beta)(ax+by)=\alpha(ax+by) +\beta(ax+by)=a(\alpha(x) +\beta(x)) +b(\alpha(y) +\beta(y))=a((\alpha+\beta) (x)) +b((\alpha+\beta) (y)) $$

Answer (score 0):

let $x,y\in u$ and $a,b\in F$ where $F$ is the field that $u$ is a linear space on.

Then from linearity of $\alpha$:

$\alpha(ax+by)=a\alpha x+b\alpha y\in v$.

And the same for $\beta$:

$\beta(ax+by)=a\beta x+b \beta y\in v$
Then:

$\alpha(ax+by)+\beta(ax+by)$ follows from the previous since $v$ is a linear space.